# Generate Matrix

Tags: matlab

I am new to MATLAB and I want to write a simple program to generate an *n x n* matrix *A* such that:
1. *a*<sub>11</sub> = 2
2. *a*<sub>22</sub> = ... = *a*<sub>nn</sub> = 5
3. 0 everywhere else

Can the program take *n* as an argument? So that I will have to choose an *n* every time I run the program.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 8;             %# input value, matrix size

A = 5.*eye(n);     %# put 5 on diagonal, zeros elsewhere
A(1,1) = 2;        %# first element
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way of doing the same.

```
n=8;
A=diag([2 5*ones(1,n-1)]);
```